# can a4j:support have more than one value in the event attribute?

Tags: richfaces, ajax4jsf

can a4j:support have more than one value in the event attribute?

```
<a:support event="onchange, onsubmit" ajaxSingle="true"
action="#{customerSession.userCheckQuantity(_cartItem, index)}"
reRender="shoppingCartAjax, orderTotalAjax"></a:support>
```

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't. In the [TLD](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/tlddoc/a4j/support.html) for the `event` attribute it says:

> Name of JavaScript event property ( onclick, onchange, etc.) of parent
>   component, for which we will build AJAX submission code

There has been a [JIRA](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-4222) requesting this feature, but it's still open. Since it's for RF3, I'm guessing this won't change.

However there is [another request](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-9984) for `a4j:ajax` (equivalent in RF4) supporting the same thing. Since it's for RF4, I'm guessing it's more likely to get implemented.

As an alternative, you can just use multiple `a4j:support` tags for one compoent:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="planets" value="#{planetsMoons.currentPlanet}" valueChangeListener="#{planetsMoons.planetChanged}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{planetsMoons.planetsList}" />
    <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="id1,id2" />
    <a4j:support event="onkeyup" reRender="id1,id3" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use actionparam for this, here is an example:

```
< a4j:commandButton ajaxSingle="true" value="Clean Up Form" reRender="name, job, out"  status="commonstatus">

                <a4j:actionparam name="n" value=""  assignTo="#{userBean.name}" />

                <a4j:actionparam name="j" value=""  assignTo="#{userBean.job}" />

< /a4j:commandButton>
```

similar for a4j:support

Comment: is it possible to declare more then one a4j:actionparam? In my case it doesn't work